# Temp and Price?

Tags: c#

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment13 { 

    class Car
    {
        int Speed = 0;
        double Temp = 0.0;

        public void setSpeed(int speed)
        {
            this.Speed = 50;
        }
        public void getSpeed()
        {
            return;
        }
        public void setTemp(double Temp)
        {
            this.Temp = 70.5;
        }
        public void getTemp()
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    class program
    {
        static void Main (string[]args)
        {
    Car ford = new Car();
    ford.setSpeed(50);
    ford.setTemp(70.5);
    Console.WriteLine("Speed = " + ford.setSpeed);
    Console.WriteLine("Temp =  " + ford.setTemp);



    Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't print out Speed and Temp // How would I add a parameter
list To correspond with the method signatures?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Speed = " + ford.get);
    Console.WriteLine("Temp =  " + ford.get);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `get` method instead of `set`...
Then you should return value as updated your code below..

```
class Car
{
    private int Speed = 0;
    private double Temp = 0.0;

    public void setSpeed(int value)
    {
        this.Speed = value;
    }
    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return Speed;
    }
    public void setTemp(double value)
    {
        this.Temp = value;
    }
    public double getTemp()
    {
        return Temp;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setSpeed(50);
        car.setTemp(20.50);
        Console.WriteLine("Speed = " + car.getSpeed());
        Console.WriteLine("Temp = " + car.getTemp());
    }
}
```

Comment: How does a void method return a value?

Comment: @RonBeyer Opps i didn't saw is void... Should change it return int... Updating the code..

Comment: @Nic still can't compile it for some reason!

Comment: @AnassElbekkari can you update your code ? and what is the exception ?

Comment: @AnassElbekkari I have updated the code to full code which will run... I tried

Comment: @Nic Thanks a lot! it works finally.  I forgot to change the parameters in the Console.WriteLine